# ifstream C++ not recognized

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm modifying a program in C++ and I need to write some values to disk.

I have added the `#include <fstream>` in the Include section and then I'¿m trying to use `ifstream` but is not recognized:

IntelliSense: identifier "ifstream" is undefined

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks,

EDIT:
Here's the code

```
#include <fstream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CommandHandling.h"
#include "Conversions.h"
#include "INIFileRW.h"
#include "ComPortTimeout.h"

CCommandHandling::CCommandHandling()
{
    /* set up com port class, start from new. */
    pCOMPort = NULL;
    pCOMPort = new Comm32Port;
    ifstream test; //Here I get the error cited above
... //More code here
...
...
...

}
```

Comment: It's in the `std` namespace?

Comment: Might be useful to show how you're using it.

Comment: it's possible that `#include <istream>` is also required (usually fstream include istream but that is not guaranteed)

Comment: I added some extra code

Comment: The code you posted doesn't show any fstreams

Comment: I Just added this code:
`using namespace std;` and everything worked just fine. Thanks Chris

Comment: `using namespace std;` @chris didn't suggest that! Don't do it; it's a bad habit that can cause namespace collisions in the future when you write meaningful code. You'll want to use fully qualified names in almost all situations until you're trying to reduce ink costs in your published book sometime in the distant future. It has the potential of causing naming conflicts/collisions in more meaningful code. Use `std::` as a prefix. `std::fstream`, `std::string`, `std::cout`, etc.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, Thank you. Apparently I'm oblivious.

Answer (score 5):

Without seeing your code, I can't be sure, but the first thing I'd try is to see if it accepts `std::ifstream`.

If that's it, then it might be worthwhile exercise to become familiar with namespaces in C++ -- they're everywhere. You can't avoid them. (Not that I suggest you should want to!)

Comment: std::ifstream works in my code..